# Cannot build multi-module Maven project with Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, maven, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a Maven project using Azure Pipelines, but I'm having troubles with it, as for some reason the `Maven@3` task seems to be unable to resolve some dependencies.
The project is structured as follows

```
Desk
 |---- desk-api
 |          \---- pom.xml
 |---- desk-implementation
 |          \---- pom.xml
 \---- pom.xml
Room
 |---- room-api
 |          \---- pom.xml
 |---- room-implementation
 |          \---- pom.xml
 \---- pom.xml
User
 |---- user-api
 |          \---- pom.xml
 |---- user-implementation
 |          \---- pom.xml
 \---- pom.xml
```

where

- `desk-implementation` depends on both `user-api` and `desk-api`
- `room-implementation` depends on both `user-api` and `room-api`
- `user-implementation` depends on every API
- the "external" POMs for each service merely invoke the POMs of the related service implementation and API.

Using `Maven@3` task I'm able to build the JARs for the APIs correctly (they're also put under `.m2/repository` folder).
However, whenever I try to build an implementation it fails. It seems the agent, when executing the task, cannot find the previously built JARs for the APIs.

This also happens when trying to build the service as a whole (this because it invokes the POM related to its implementation, but fails as previously explained).

I tried to copy the JARs into `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and into each implementation folder, but again those JARs were not found.
I checked the permissions and they're fine and so are the goals I use when building.

Looking for some answers, it seems that the only way to solve this issue is by using Azure Artifacts and modifying the POMs accordingly.
I find it very weird: some colleagues of mine (working on the same Maven project, but using Jenkins instead of Azure Pipelines) manage to build it beautifully.
Is it really not possible to build a multi-module Maven project in Azure Pipelines without using Azure Artifacts?